# Insert one dimensional array into multidimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I'm looking for a way to input 4 one-dimensional arrays into a 4x4 multidimensional array.

In the time I've spent looking for this I've found that it seems much simpler to do with jagged arrays.  However, I feel like I'm missing something obvious and would like to ask for help.

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
{
    //reads in 4 separate values e.g. A B C D
    unitReader = sr.ReadLine();  

    //creates a char array with 4 separate elements
    char[] line = unitReader.ToCharArray();

    //places that array into a bigger jagged array
    fullArray[x] = line; 

    //just to test that it's worked
    Console.WriteLine(fullArray[x]);
}
```

this is how I've been able to do it with the jagged array which is defined earlier as:

```
char[][] fullArray = new char[4][];
```

Is there code similar to this that would allow me to assign values by line to a multidimensional array without having to do 16 passes to assign individual elements?

Comment: why don't you like 16 assigns?

Comment: @shibormot - Scalability concern maybe?  Perhaps his array might be 16 x 16 or 32 x 32 someday?

Comment: @bootski check this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx arrays sometimes are required only for performance issues

Comment: What's a "standard" array?

Comment: @shibormot as Tim mentioned, if I ever need to do this larger, it gets out of hand quickly. e.g. 6x6 array = 36 assigns

Comment: @JohnSaunders standard array meaning a normal array like the `line` variable used in my sample code.

Comment: That's just a one-dimensional array. "n"-dimensional arrays are "standard" for any n>0 (up to your available memory, I believe). Perhaps you meant to contrast it with a jagged array?

Comment: Do you think about 4x4x4 or 6x6x6x6x6 arrays in future?

Comment: @JohnSaunders using that nomenclature, my question would read: how do you assign a 1 dimensional array's values into a multidimensional array (not a jagged) without having to assign each element individually (as I've done with the jagged array in my sample code)?

Comment: I think that's the correct title, yet. You should edit your question and change your title to make it clearer. You'll get better answers that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for **Buffer.BlockCopy()**

For more details, see [Documentation of BufferCopy.BlockCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx)

Comment: ah, very nice. i'm going to look into this and i'll come back and mark you as answer if it is. looks promising.

Comment: this is the only way i can find that allows for what i asked in a simple(ish) way.  however, due to both the complexity of this solution and scaling, i decided to stick to jagged arrays. thanks minhcat_vo.

Answer (score 0):

for scalability you can try custom collections like this

```
public class FixedSizeCollection<T> : Collection<T>
{
    protected bool _initializing;
    public int Size { get; private set; }

    public FixedSizeCollection(int size)
    {
        Size = size;
        Init();
    }

    public FixedSizeCollection(int size, IList<T> list) 
    {
        Size = size;
        Init();
        if (list.Count != Size)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Changing size is not supported.");

        foreach (T item in list)
            Items[list.IndexOf(item)] = item;
    }

    protected virtual void Init()
    {
        _initializing = true;
        base.ClearItems();
        for (int j = 0; j < Size; j++)
            Add(default(T));
        _initializing = false;
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        Init();
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        if (!_initializing)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Changing size is not supported.");
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        if (!_initializing)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Changing size is not supported.");
        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
    {
        base.SetItem(index, item);
    }
}

public class SquareArray<T> : FixedSizeCollection<FixedSizeCollection<T>>
{
    public SquareArray(int size) : base(size)
    {
    }

    protected override void Init()
    {
        _initializing = true;
        for (int i = 0; i< Size; i++)
        {
            FixedSizeCollection<T> row = new FixedSizeCollection<T>(Size);
            Add(row);
        }
        _initializing = false;
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, FixedSizeCollection<T> item)
    {
        if (item.Count != Size)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Changing size is not supported.");
        base.SetItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

then your loop will be looked like that:

```
SquareArray<char> fullarray = new SquareArray(4);

for (int x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
{
    //reads in 4 separate values e.g. A B C D
    unitReader = sr.ReadLine();  

    //creates a char array with 4 separate elements
    char[] line = unitReader.ToCharArray();

    //places that array into a bigger jagged array
    fullArray[x] = new FixedSizeCollection(4, line); 

    //just to test that it's worked
    Console.WriteLine(fullArray[x]);
}
```

Comment: thanks. while this probably does address scalability, it doesn't address the multidimensional-array question. also, it's a little over-complicated for me as i'm fairly new to this (as you can probably tell).