# Appending 1D arrays together in a multidimensional array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, append

I know a similar question was already asked for [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095751/insert-one-dimensional-array-into-multidimensional-array), but is there a way for me to append individual, 1D vectors (with possibly different lengths) together to form a multidimensional array? For example, I'd like a take 4 individual 1D arrays, of length 7, 10, 13, and 16 together into a (7,10,13,16) array.

I've tried methods similar to the following, but to no avail.

```
np.concatenate((data0[...,np.newaxis], data1[..., np.newaxis]), axis=2)
```

EDIT 1:
To illustrate my end goal, let's assume that you want to know the efficiency of a car. You have 4 parameters: car width, car height, body composition, and model year. Together, these create a process space in which the efficiency of the car can vary. Each parameter is represented by a vector of different values; each vector has a different number of value elements. With this, you'd have 4 parameters + Car Efficiency. I'd like to construct a (5D) array of these 5 vectors.

Answer (score 0):

`take 4 individual 1D arrays, of length 7, 10, 13, and 16 together into a (7,10,13,16) array`

In `numpy`, a tuple like `(7,10,13,16)` usually refers to the `shape`.  In this case it looks like a 4 dimensional array with 7*10*13*16 elements.

But more realistically I think you want a list of these 4 arrays

```
[[1,2...,7], [0,2,...9], [1,...13], etc]
```

Those can't be turned into a multidimensional array.  Such an array has to have equal numbers of rows, columns, etc., not a ragged set.

There is such a thing as an array with `dtype=object`, where the elements can be lists, arrays, None, or any Python object.  I'm almost reluctant to mention it because too many SO questions seem to misuse it.  In most case, a plain Python list works just as well.

To get more help, you need to clearer about what you seek.

When you say something like `I've tried methods similar to the following, but to no avail.` - you really should say what is wrong.  What kind of errror did you get?  Error messages?  Or was the result just not what you want?  Details (but not too many! :) ) make a good question.

---

To make a 'process space', you can do something like:

Small sample arrays:

```
In [676]: heights=np.array([40,50])
In [677]: widths=np.array([60,65,70])
In [678]: yrs=np.array([1995,1996,1997,1998])
```

An all 0 space of the correct size:

```
In [679]: eff=np.zeros((2,3,4))
```

An 'efficiency' calculation combining all values with a formula

```
In [680]: eff1=(yrs-1994)[None,None,:]/(heights[:,None,None]+widths[None,:,None])
In [681]: eff1.shape
Out[681]: (2, 3, 4)
In [682]: eff1
Out[682]: 
array([[[ 0.01      ,  0.02      ,  0.03      ,  0.04      ],
        [ 0.00952381,  0.01904762,  0.02857143,  0.03809524],
        [ 0.00909091,  0.01818182,  0.02727273,  0.03636364]],

       [[ 0.00909091,  0.01818182,  0.02727273,  0.03636364],
        [ 0.00869565,  0.0173913 ,  0.02608696,  0.03478261],
        [ 0.00833333,  0.01666667,  0.025     ,  0.03333333]]])
```

`ix_` is a convenience function to add all those `None`, simplifying the expression to:

```
In [695]: H,W,Y=np.ix_(heights,widths, yrs)
In [696]: eff1=(Y-1994)/(H+W)
```

I can easily convert each one of these input arrays to `(2,3,4)` array with:

```
HH, WW, YY = np.broadcast_arrays(H,W,Y)
```

But if you are envisioning a complex 'table' with row and column labels, you might be better off using `pandas`.

---

A non-numpy way of constructing a 'space' is with `itertools.product`

```
In [704]: import itertools
In [705]: list(itertools.product(heights,widths,yrs))
Out[705]: 
[(40, 60, 1995),
 (40, 60, 1996),
 (40, 60, 1997),
 (40, 60, 1998),
 (40, 65, 1995),
 (40, 65, 1996),
 ...
 (50, 70, 1996),
 (50, 70, 1997),
 (50, 70, 1998)]
```

Comment: "[...] it looks like a 4 dimensional array with 7*10*13*16 elements." -- This is precisely what I'm after. My apologies for not including more details, thank you for the heads up!

As an end result, I would like to end up with a matrix, ex. "data", where the 'Size' parameter in the Variable Explorer shows (7,10,13,16).  I tried your suggested list of 4 arrays, `data = [[1,2...,7], [0,2,...9], [1,...13], etc]`. But using this method, the 'size' column shows 4.

 but the size of this is shown as 4

Comment: It's easy with `broadcasting` to make an array of this shape.  But how do you want to use the array values?  Multiplied together?  Added?  Use one and ignore the rest?  Many, many options.  Demonstrate with a couple of small arrays.

Comment: It is better to add details to your original question; it's hard to read long comments.  But, look at my edits to see what I'm asking for.